# How to send by post method in laravel by means of a button an array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request, laravel-blade

I have on blade this

```
    @foreach($list as $item)
        <tr class="columnsArray">
            <td>{{$item["lista"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["oficina_ventas"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["lista_precios"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["tipo_precio"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["nit"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["producto"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["material"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["unidad_medida"]}}</td>
            <td>${{$item["precio_actual"]}}</td>
            <td>${{$item["nuevo_precio"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["fecha_inicio"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["cod"]}}</td>
            <td>{{$item["cliente"]}}</td>

        </tr>

        @endforeach
    </table>

   <div class="botonEnviar"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">ENVIAR</button></div>
```

The foreach is to show but I want to send that same list when I click the button,method "post"

the route is:

```
$app->post('notification','AtlanticControllerChangePrice@notification');
```

And the function is:

```
    function notification(Request $request){
    return $request;
}
```

Return request because for test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create hidden inputs for each of your list item:

```html
<form method="post" action="/notification">
  <table>
    @foreach($list as $item)
      <input type="hidden" name="lista" value="{{ $item['lista'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="oficina_ventas" value="{{ $item['oficina_ventas'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="lista_precios" value="{{ $item['lista_precios'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="tipo_precio" value="{{ $item['tipo_precio'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="nit" value="{{ $item['nit'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="producto" value="{{ $item['producto'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="material" value="{{ $item['material'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="unidad_medida" value="{{ $item['unidad_medida'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="precio_actual" value="${{ $item['precio_actual'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="nuevo_precio" value="${{ $item['nuevo_precio'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="fecha_inicio" value="{{ $item['fecha_inicio'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="cod" value="{{ $item['cod'] }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="cliente" value="{{ $item['cliente'] }}">
    
      <tr class="columnsArray">
        <td>{{$item["lista"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["oficina_ventas"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["lista_precios"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["tipo_precio"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["nit"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["producto"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["material"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["unidad_medida"]}}</td>
        <td>${{$item["precio_actual"]}}</td>
        <td>${{$item["nuevo_precio"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["fecha_inicio"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["cod"]}}</td>
        <td>{{$item["cliente"]}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>  


<div class="botonEnviar">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">ENVIAR</button>
</div>

</form>
```

It's not looking good, but it's your solution

Comment: Thanks,but,
it does not work when 
I click on send...No error occurs but,does nothing

Comment: I edited code. Submit button was out of form, It should be inside form element